# Upgrade Symfony2 2.3 to 2.4: Change composer.json

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to upgrade a project from Symfony 2.3 to 2.4. I've readed that the 2.4 version has backward compatibility with 2.3 and is only necessary to update de components version.

This is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name" : "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description" : "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "type" : "project",
    "license" : [
            "MIT"
    ],
    "require" : {
            "symfony/symfony" : "2.3.*",
            "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle" : "dev-master",
            "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "2.3.*",
            "doctrine/orm" : ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
            "doctrine/data-fixtures" : "dev-master",
            "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "2.3.*",
            "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
            "twig/extensions" : "1.0.*",
            "php" : ">=5.3.3",
            "sensio/generator-bundle" : "2.3.*",
            "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "2.4.*",
            "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "2.3.*",
            "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "1.2.*",
            "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "2.3.*",
            "liip/imagine-bundle": "dev-master",
            "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "*"
    },
    "autoload" : {
            "psr-0" : {
                    "" : "src/"
            }
    },
    "minimum-stability" : "stable",
    "config" : {
            "bin-dir" : "bin"
    },
    "scripts" : {
            "post-update-cmd" : [
                    "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
                    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
                    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
                    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
                    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
            ],
            "post-install-cmd" : [
                    "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
                    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
                    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
                    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
                    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
            ]
    },
    "extra" : {
            "branch-alias" : {
                    "dev-master" : "2.3-dev"
            },
            "symfony-web-dir" : "web",
            "symfony-app-dir" : "app",
            "incenteev-parameters" : {
                    "file" : "app/config/parameters.yml"
            }
    }
}
```

But when I check [the v2.4 composer.json file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.4/composer.json) is very different from this.

I've tried to change my composer.json for the 2.4 version, add my custom bundles and make a "composer update", but it didn't work.

Would it be enough to update the versions of the bundles that installs the 2.4 version on my own composer.json?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Symfony 2.4 composer.json file is next:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "beta",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Compare the third-party libraries in **require** section that You have used in your project with third-party libraries in v 2.4. If you don't use any missed libs in new version, you can update. But create a backup before.

Comment: With this composer.json the update has worked perfecly. I just have to add my custom bundles and "doctrine/data-fixtures" + "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle". Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. @hanzi below also give the link to the [composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.4/composer.json) file of symfony-standard-editin on github, which I gave in my example.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at the wrong `composer.json`. Try this one:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.4/composer.json

**Explanation:** The `symfony/symfony` repository is the framework itself -- but you do not want to clone the framework, only depend on it. That's why you'd rather use the `symfony/symfony-standard` repository, which is basically a template for projects that rely on the Symfony framework. As is yours.

Comment: Thanks @hanzi. Now I understand how the Symfony github is organized.